# Getting RSA exponent from public key

Tags: c#, rsa, exponent

I'm using RSA to encrypt and decrypt some messages. It works great, but I also need a way to get exponent and convert it to string so I can write it in simple text file. I'm using RSACryotoServiceProvider.

Edit 1 (using BigInteger):

```
byte[] e_jav=javni_klj.Exponent;
BigInteger bigInteger=new BigInteger(e_jav);
MessageBox.Show("e: " + bigInteger);
```

Comment: You can get the keys with `ExportParameters()`

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085417/rsa-modulus-and-exponent-from-public-key) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it says that array im storing it in is not bit enough. Tried storing it in int, int 64, Uint64 etc. Nothing works. Any examples of it or anything ? I can get "n" and "d" for private key without problem, but it just can't get "e" to convert it to string. It says it's too big... I don't really know what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: `BigInteger` is what you would have to use.  Even `Decimal` is limited to 29 significant digits.

Comment: Thanks, but since im not really skillful in programming, can you please help me with using BigInteger ? I referenced the dll in my project and BigInteger works, but I don't know how to use it. I tried getting the byte array into BigInteger, and every time it gives me the same number which is: 65537. And as far as i remember, exponent should be different everytime (it should be random).

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question so we can better help you.  Prefix each line with four spaces to format it.

Comment: byte[] e_jav=javni_klj.Exponent; BigInteger bigInteger=new BigInteger(e_jav); Sorry, don't know how to paste code, but this is what i use.

Comment: Click the "Edit" link under the question and add your code there, not in a comment.  Please post a more complete sample of your code.

Comment: @Amy Thanks, code is now posted in edit.

Comment: @Bogy [65537 is correct](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537) so everything is fine.

Comment: @Progman Thank you so much. I thought i was doing something wrong since it was the same number every time. Thank you, you helped alot.